# significance of providing Redirect Uri in google api console

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth

For OAuth 2.0 implementation we need to create a project in Google Developer Console
Wanted to understand what is the significance of providing Redirect Uri.

Comment: to -1'ers it really is a valid question even if it is a bit short.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation [Google Oauth2](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp)

> Determines where the response is sent. The value of this parameter
>   must exactly match one of the values that appear in the Credentials
>   page in the Google Developers Console (including the http or https
>   scheme, case, and trailing slash). You may choose between
>   urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob, urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto, or an
>   http:// localhost port. For more details, see Choosing a redirect URI.

Basically when you authenticate a web application Google needs to know where to send the response back to.  Normally this is the name of the file that is able to process that response.  http//yoursite.com/oauth2.php   for native applications like a windows program you can use localhost for debugging.